# Mongodb not connecting in VScode

Tags: mongodb

I’m new to coding. But this just doesn’t make sense. All the videos I’ve watched set up mongodb differently. I am able to connect to the local host, but not to the database on mongodb. I use the string and input the correct username and password. But I still get etimedout. If I have to start from scratch I’ll be okay with that. I just want to get to the part where I start adding data to the database

I’ve tried everything. I don’t know where I went wrong.

Comment: Its impossible to say where you went wrong - we know nothing about what you did. Please provide your code that you use for connecting to mongodb and other relevant details.

Comment: I set up a cluster in mongodb, I then went to vscode and installed the extension mongodb. After trying for three days now I’ve been able to connect to the local host through form on the extension. But am unable to connect to my cluster. I’ve also tried to connect with mongoshell. I am getting timed out. I apologize about lack of information about what I’ve done. I’ve followed the tutorials and gotten this far, as far as code goes. I haven’t added any code as of yet.

Comment: I have gone though the videos using code to connect, but those are 6 months to 2 years ago. Nothing up to date. And I haven’t seen any literature with my issue.

Comment: Try to explain *exactly* how you are trying to connect to mongodb. What do you type? where do you type it? How do you submit the command? What is the result you get when you do? If you are following a tutorial, what tutorial are you following? Show what you implemented based on the tutorial. Note that tutorial 6 months to 2 years old is probably fine - I don't think mongodb will have completely changed the way you connect to it in this time.

Comment: It’s a free cluster database and after hitting connect it produces a connection string, I copy and paste that in the mongodb connect command palette.

Comment: After hitting connect I get an error saying it’s etimedout. Since this way did not connect me, I tired to follow other videos that seem to just click and connect. I thought the coding vids weren’t applicable since their other vids didn’t have any to complete the task.

Comment: I want to learn how to do it. Just can’t find any from point a to point b information.

Comment: A timeout error may mean that your cluster is not set up to take connections correctly. "I have a free cluster database" is too vague. Most sites that provide such services provide documentation on how to use them. In any case, if you don't tell us what service you are using, how can we possible answer your questions about how to use it?

Comment: When creating the database I didn’t get too much documentation. Thought the instructions using vscode it tells me to apply the connection string to the extension.

Comment: Sorry its just impossible to understand you. What is the exact meaning of "apply a connection string to an extension"? What did you do? How did you do it?

Comment: Trying to connect mongodb cluster to vscode. It produced “connect to your mongodb deployment” and it gives me a connection string to put into the command palette. I can’t seem to connect to the cluster on the through the mongodb extension in vscode. I just followed the instructions on setup. Install extension create a database produce a connection string for vscode. But I am not connected

Comment: I haven’t done anything outside of that

Comment: What do you mean by "I am able to connect to the localhost, but not to the database on mongodb"? This statement does not make any sense. I doubt that you setup a MongoDB sharded **cluster** - that's a rather difficult task.

Comment: From what you have written so far, your MongoDB may not run, did you start the database? Did you read the documentation (Connect to a Deployment)[https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/connect/]? Or [MongoDB for VS Code](https://www.mongodb.com/products/vs-code). Just a note, you can use MongoDB from local installation or from MongoDB cloud service (MongoDB Atlas) - don't mix them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, few things to take into consideration .

1. Using mongoose: It makes your work a lot easier and makes your database code
   clean and readable.
2. Mongoose does not accept callbacks anymore , so we will use then and catch
   blocks.
3. Compass: If you are using Mongodb for 1st time , I'll suggest Compass which
   is good for seeing  the data in gui .(optional)
   Now let's code .

> Before that be sure to install mongoose via npm.

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

> Defining schema

```
  const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String,
});

//base
const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
mongoose
  .connect(
    "MONGO_URI"
  )
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to Db");

//createnew user


  const newUser = new User({
      name: "waka",
      email: "@gmail",
    });

    return newUser.save();
  })

      .then(() => {
        console.log("saved successfully");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Failed");
      });
```

if it still does not work , then in place of localhost in the uri ,try putting

```
0.0.0.0:
```

This should work now .

Comment: mongoose is an add-on for MongoDB and not part of the question at all. He tries to run a MongoDB, don't stress him with additional libraries. `mongodb+srv:..` is used to connect to MongoDB Atlas cloud service which is not in question either. And using IP `0.0.0.0` is also a bad approach. Your answer is completely pointless.